# How to use Refresh token of firebase

Tags: php, firebase, jwt, refresh-token

What is the expiry time of refresh token? Can I get new token if used with refresh token. If yes Is there any time limit for refresh token .

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication uses two tokens:

- a long-lived/permanent **refresh token** that identifies the user.
- a short-lived **ID token** that grants the user access to backend services.

The *refresh token* doesn't expire.

The *ID token* by default expires hourly. If you mint a custom token you can set a custom expiration, which can never be longer than an hour.

Comment: So can we use this refresh token to authenticate a user,if his authentication is lost after an hour

Comment: No. All of this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) btw. What are you trying to accomplish here?